# How to communicate (network) with Docker at DigitalOcean?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to use [Docker - Build, Ship, and Run Any App, Anywhere](https://www.docker.com/) with [Simple Cloud Infrastructure for Developers | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), using following container: [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/nagev/tor/), [np1/docker-tor-clientonly](https://github.com/np1/docker-tor-clientonly).

Per author's instructions, I was able to run container:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
bdcdabe8ab1d        nagev/tor           "/bin/sh -c '/usr/loc"   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       127.0.1.1:9150->9150/tcp   tor_instance
mbp:~ alexus$
```

What IP address should I use to set proxy inside of my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the IP address of a machine:

```
mbp:~ alexus$ docker-machine ip alexus
X.X.X.X
mbp:~ alexus$
```

yet, to resolve my issue, even though per developer's instructions `-p 127.0.1.1:9150:9150` was used, that what prevented me to connecting to it remotely, so I use `docker-machine ip droplet` instead of `127.0.0.1` and now it works!)